# Scraper build with nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have t3a.small instance on aws, I  written a small script for scraping the products of a website.
THere are total 9071 records in the mongodb. Now I have to get menus from these link.
Below is my code

```
router.get('/restaurant-stream',(req,res) => {
    var Model = helper.getModel('restaurants');
    var total_records = 0;
    var completed_counter = 0;
    var search = {
        source_content : {
            $ne : {}
        }
    };
    var counter = 0;

    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {

        // count the total records in the db table
        Model.countDocuments(search,(error,count) => {
            if(error){
                reject(error.toString());
            }else{
                total_records = count;
                console.log('\n\n\t\t Total restaurants : ',total_records);
                resolve()
            }
        })
    })
    .then(response => {
        const WorkerThread = require('worker_threads');
        const join = require('path').join;

        if(! WorkerThread.isMainThread){
            debug('Main worker thread');
            return;
        }
        const stream = Model.find(search).stream();

        try{
            stream.on('data', (restaurant) => {
                restaurant._id = restaurant._id.toString();
                const worker = new WorkerThread.Worker(join(__dirname,'./restaurant-stream.js'),{
                    workerData: {
                        value: restaurant,
                        index : counter
                    }
                });
                worker.on('message', (result) => {
    
                    if(result.response)
                    {
                        var resData = result.response;
                        
                        Model.updateOne({_id:mongoose.Types.ObjectId(restaurant._id)},{
                            menus : resData.menus,
                            address : resData.address,
                            street : resData.street,
                            city : resData.city,
                            state : resData.state,
                            post_code : resData.post_code,
                            cuisine : resData.cuisine,
                            latitude : resData.latitude,
                            longitude : resData.longitude,
                            contact_number : resData.contact_number,
                            image_bg_url : resData.image_bg_url,
                            disclaimerBadge : resData.disclaimerBadge,
                            is_filled : 0
                        }).exec((error,success) => {
                            if(error){
                                console.log('\n\t\t '+ result.index +' Restaurant : ',restaurant.slug + ' Failed');
                            }else{
                                console.log('\n\t\t '+ result.index +' Restaurant : ',restaurant.slug + ' updated');
                            }
                            completed_counter++;
                            if(total_records == completed_counter){
                                console.log('\n\n\t\t All restaurants processed successfully');
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
                
                worker.on('error', (err)=>{
                    console.log('error',err);
                })
    
                worker.on('exit', (e)=>{
                    //console.log('Worker exit successfully!',e);
                });
    
                counter++;
            });
    
            stream.on('end', () => {
                //console.log('All restaurants processed successfully')
                res.send('Processing of restaurants started ' + counter);
            });
    
            stream.on('error', error => {
                debug('error : ',error);
            });
        }catch(e){
            debug('catch block',e);
            res.send({message:e.toString(),status:'error'});
        }
    })
    .catch(error => {
        res.send({message:error.toString(),status:'error'});
    })
})
```

After some time the ec2 instance hangs and do nothing, I also not able to login for few minutes to the instance. Is this a bad approach or how can I improve my code to make it work on ec2 instance.

restaurant-stream code

// below code is for debuging purpose

```
Object.defineProperty(global, '__stack', {
    get: function(){
        var orig = Error.prepareStackTrace;
        Error.prepareStackTrace = function(_, stack){ return stack; };
        var err = new Error;
        Error.captureStackTrace(err, arguments.callee);
        var stack = err.stack;
        Error.prepareStackTrace = orig;
        return stack;
    }
  });
  
Object.defineProperty(global, '__line', {
    get: function(){
        return __stack[1].getLineNumber();
    }
});

Array.prototype.random = function () {
    return this[Math.floor((Math.random()*this.length))];
}
const join = require('path').join;
var fs = require('fs');
var file = fs.readFileSync(join(__dirname,'../public/browseragents.txt'),'utf-8');
var userAgents = file.split('\n').random();

const debug = require('debug')('app');
const JLog = require('../libs/logger');
const WorkerThreads = require('worker_threads');
const { parentPort, workerData } = require('worker_threads');
if(WorkerThreads.isMainThread){
    debug('Main thread');
    return;
}

var fetchMenus = (restaurant,index = 0) => {
    
    return new Promise(async(resolve,reject) => {
        try{
            var resData = await scrapRestaurant(restaurant.source_content,restaurant.uuid);
            resolve({data:resData,index:index});
        }catch(e){
            JLog('Error in fetching menus : ' + e.toString(),__filename,__line);
            debug(e);
            reject(e.toString());
        }
    })
}

var scrapRestaurant = (source_content,uuid) => {

    var base_url = 'https://dd';
    var resDetail = {
        'uuid':uuid,
        'image_bg_url' : '',
        'address' : '',
        'street' : '',
        'city' : '',
        'country' : '',
        'post_code' : '',
        'state' : '',
        'latitude' : '',
        'longitude' : '',
        'contact_number' : '',
        'cuisine' : '',
        'menus': {
            'breakfast':{
                "uuid":'',
                "categories":[]
            },
            'lunch_dinner':{
                "uuid":'',
                "categories":[]
            },
            'all_time':{
                "uuid":'',
                "categories":[]
            },
        },
        'source_content' : '',
        'disclaimerBadge' : '',
    };
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {

        //debug('\n\t\t\t GOT THE SOURCE ');

        resDetail['source_content'] = source_content;

        if(source_content[uuid])
        {
            resolve(source_content[uuid]['data'])
        }else{
            debug(uuid,source_content)
            reject({error:'No restaurant object found', line:__line});
        }
    })
    .then(restaurant => {

        return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {

            if(restaurant['disclaimerBadge']){
                resDetail['disclaimerBadge'] = restaurant['disclaimerBadge']['text'];
            }   

            // get the background big image
            
            if(restaurant['heroImageUrls'].length > 0)
            {
                resDetail['image_bg_url'] = restaurant['heroImageUrls'][restaurant  ['heroImageUrls'].length - 1]['url'];
            }

            if(restaurant['location']['address'])
            {
                resDetail['address'] = restaurant['location']['address'];
            }


            if(restaurant['location']['streetAddress'])
            {
                resDetail['street'] = restaurant['location']['streetAddress'];
            }

            if(restaurant['location']['city'])
            {
                resDetail['city'] = restaurant['location']['city'];
            }

            if(restaurant['location']['country'])
            {
                resDetail['country'] = restaurant['location']['country'];
            }

            if(restaurant['location']['postalCode'])
            {
                resDetail['post_code'] = restaurant['location']['postalCode'];
            }

            if(restaurant['location']['region'])
            {
                resDetail['state'] = restaurant['location']['region'];
            }

            if(restaurant['location']['latitude'])
            {
                resDetail['latitude'] = restaurant['location']['latitude'];
            }

            if(restaurant['location']['longitude'])
            {
                resDetail['longitude'] = restaurant['location']['longitude'];
            }

            if(restaurant['phoneNumber'])
            {
                resDetail['contact_number'] = restaurant['phoneNumber'];
            }


            if(restaurant['cuisineList'])
            {
                resDetail['cuisine'] = restaurant['cuisineList'].join(',');
            }
            resolve(restaurant);
        })
    })
    .then(restaurant => {

        return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
            //debug('section ',restaurant['sections'])
            // get the menus of the restaurant
            if(restaurant['sections'].length == 0)
            {
                reject(resDetail)
            }else{
                restaurant['sections'].forEach(section => {
                    var categories = [];
                    section.subsectionUuids.forEach(catID => {
                        categories.push({
                            uuid : restaurant['subsectionsMap'][catID].uuid,
                            menu_uuid : section.uuid,
                            category_title : restaurant['subsectionsMap'][catID].title,
                            category_item_ids : restaurant['subsectionsMap'][catID].itemUuids,
                            category_items : []
                        });
                    })

                    if(section.title.toLowerCase() == 'breakfast' || /^breakfast/.test(section.title.toLowerCase())){
                        resDetail['menus'].breakfast = {
                            uuid : section.uuid,
                            categories : categories
                        };
                    }else if(section.title.toLowerCase() == 'lunch & dinner'){
                        resDetail['menus'].lunch_dinner = {
                            uuid : section.uuid,
                            categories : categories
                        };
                    }else if(section.title.toLowerCase() == 'lunch menu'){
                        resDetail['menus'].lunch_dinner = {
                            uuid : section.uuid,
                            categories : categories
                        };
                    }else{
                        resDetail['menus'].all_time = {
                            uuid : section.uuid,
                            categories : categories
                        };
                    }
                })
                resolve(restaurant);
            }
        })
    })
    .then(restaurant => {

        return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {

            for(var [item,value] of Object.entries(resDetail['menus'])){

               if(value.categories.length > 0)
               {
                    value.categories.forEach((cat,index) => {

                        if(cat.category_item_ids.length > 0){
                            
                            var catItems = {};
                            cat.category_item_ids.forEach(itemID => {
                                if(typeof(restaurant['sectionEntitiesMap'][cat.menu_uuid][itemID]) != 'undefined'){
                                    catItems = {
                                        uuid : restaurant['sectionEntitiesMap'][cat.menu_uuid][itemID].uuid,
                                        title : restaurant['sectionEntitiesMap'][cat.menu_uuid][itemID].title,
                                        price : restaurant['sectionEntitiesMap'][cat.menu_uuid][itemID].price,
                                        description : restaurant['sectionEntitiesMap'][cat.menu_uuid][itemID].description,
                                        image_url : restaurant['sectionEntitiesMap'][cat.menu_uuid][itemID].imageUrl,
                                        image : '',
                                        addons : []
                                    }
                                    resDetail['menus'][item]['categories'][index]['category_items'].push(catItems);
                                }
                            })
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
            resolve(restaurant);
        })
    })
    .then(restaurant => {

        return new Promise(async (resolve,reject) => {

            for(var [item,value] of Object.entries(resDetail['menus'])){
                try{
                    if(value.categories.length > 0)
                    {
                        for(let [index,cat] of value.categories.entries())
                        {
                            if(cat.category_items.length > 0){

                                for(let [cat_index,cat_item] of cat.category_items.entries())
                                {
                                    if(typeof(resDetail['menus'][item]['categories'][index]['category_items'][cat_index]) != 'undefined'){
                                        
                                       var addons = await fetchAddons(cat_item.uuid,value.uuid,cat.uuid,resDetail['uuid']);
                                       if(addons){
                                            resDetail['menus'][item]['categories'][index]['category_items'][cat_index]['addons'] = addons;
                                       }
                                       
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }catch(e){
                    debug('addons',e);
                }
            }
            resolve(resDetail)
        })
    })
}

var fetchAddons = (a,b,c,d) => {

    var addons = {
        item_description : '',
        item_image : '',
        addons : [],
        source_content : {}
    };
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        
        var axios = require('axios');
        axios.post('https://addon_url',{
            
        },{
            headers: {
                'x-csrf-token':'x',
                //'pragma' : 'no-cache',
                //'Accept': 'application/json',
                'User-Agent':file.split('\n').random()
            },
            timeout : 60*60*60
        })
        .then(response => {
            if(response['data']['status'] == 'success'){
                resolve(response['data']['data']);
            }else{
                reject({error:'No data found',line:__line});
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            //console.log('ADDONS ERROR ' + menuItemUuid + ' ' + sectionUuid + ' ' + subsectionUuid + ' ' + storeUuid + ' ' + error.toString(),__filename,__line)
            debug(error);
            reject();
        })
    })
    .then(response => {

        return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
            try{
                // prepare the addons list
                addons['item_description'] = response.itemDescription;
                addons['item_image'] = response.imageUrl;
                addons['addons'] = response['customizationsList'];
                addons['source_content'] = response;
            }catch(e){
                console.log(e);
            }
            resolve(addons);
        })
    })
}

var res = fetchMenus(workerData.value,workerData.index)
res.then(
    response => {
        parentPort.postMessage({
            response: response.data,
            index : response.index
        });
    }
)
.catch(error => {
    parentPort.postMessage({
        error: true,
        err: error
    });
})
```

Comment: Why do you need a worker for each restaurant database record? A t3a.small only really caters for 2 threads if you are doing some heavy processing in `restaurant-stream.js`.

Comment: Can you describe the process you are trying to run in parallel?

Comment: I have put the code of restaurant-stream you can see what I was doing. What I want is run the scrapping of menus of each restaurants parallel so that it can finish as soon as poosible.

Comment: As you have found, creating 9071 worker threads is not going to make anything faster. File/Network IO is already completed on separate threads in Node JS. The async axios requests already allow for parralellism. You will be pushing a t3a.small instance running on just the main thread.

Comment: Focus on learning about using async/await with promises first. Then extend for performance later